# No Session after logging in

Tags: php

I have a strange issue. I've create a login page in PHP that works fine. I've decided to destroy any session when a user hits the login page. But, by doing this the user is never logged in. I can't see the issue.

Login page

```
<?php
session_start();

// Destroy any active session
session_destroy();

// Regenerate Session ID
session_regenerate_id(true);

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);

    if(strlen($username) > 12) {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=addcovers;host=127.0.0.1', 'root', '');
        $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT display_name FROM users WHERE username = :username && password = :password');
        $sth->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
        $sth->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR, 32);
        $sth->execute();
        $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        if($result) {
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
            $_SESSION['user'] = $result->display_name;
            header('Location: index.php');
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        // DEBUG: echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

}
?>
<!DOCTYLE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css" type="text/css" media="all">
</head>

<body id="admin-login">
    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <div><label for="username">Username</label><input type="text" name="username" maxlength="12"></div>
            <div><label for="password">Password</label><input type="password" name="password"></div>
            <button type="submit">Admin Login</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
```

Admin Page

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) header('Location: login.php');

echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['user'];

?>
```

If I remove the `session_destroy` from the login page it works fine. Currently though the user keeps hitting the login page even if the credentials are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do a header-location redirect immediately after changing the session id. You are creating a new session id, but the new one isn't being sent back to the browser because you do a redirect. So the browser continues to use the old session id (which is empty, because you destroyed it).

Note PHP's docmuentation:

> Session ID is not passed with Location header even if
>   session.use_trans_sid is enabled. It must by passed manually using SID
>   constant.

As to how to fix it, I'm not sure. A quick search doesn't show much. Perhaps you need to read the SID constant and manually send the correct headers for the new session id back to the browser, as part of your redirect.

Or you could show one of those "you have been logged in" messages for a second, then use javascript or a `<meta>` tag to redirect to `index.php`.

Also note This line of code:

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

Will only send a header response for the *current* request which is to `login.php`. It will still continue executing your script. In general you should always exit after sending that header:

```
header('Location: index.php');
exit;
```

I don't think that will cause your bug, but you should fix it.

Comment: Yeah, that's right: I think this was one of the "unclear" problems with session.

Comment: If he's using cookies (which is true by default) the SID is totally not relevant to the problem here because it's communicated through a cookie. The documentation clearly states, and common sense dictates, that you simply need to set the cookie again with `session_start`. There is nothing preventing you from doing that, because you are still in the "headers being sent" phase -- after all, the code successfully performs a HTTP redirect *after* destroying the session.

Answer (score 0):

What if you comment out this line in `index.php` ?

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) header('Location: login.php');
```

(That is: does the `index.php` see stuff in the session? Try also by printing a `var_export($_SESSION);`)

I remember that PHP sessions were giving some apparently random issues, depending on `$_SESSION` not being global, for what I remember; but your code seems to be in the global scope.. am I right?

Answer (score 0):

There is no benefit to calling `session_destroy` just before logging the user in (or indeed when the user simply *visits* the login page, as your script currently does) -- and even if you really want to do that, this is not the correct way to do it.

The documentation for [`session_destroy`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) says that after calling it,

> To use the session variables again, `session_start()` has to be called.

You don't do this, so the session variables you set later do not "stick" and the admin page redirects back to login.

If you do want to completely destroy the user session, then:

1. Follow the example in the docs: destroy the session, regenerate the id, unset `$_SESSION` and also unset the session cookie.
2. Do this only if the user has passed the username/password check, not unconditionally.
3. Call `session_start` again before setting any session variables for the new session.

Comment: Well, there are some cases where I'd request the user to re-log in, such as when changing passwords etc. and then redirect them to where they came from. The session destroy is only being called if a user revisits the page, which they wouldn't do manually if they were already logged in.

Comment: @JamesJeffery: Requiring that the user authenticate themselves again does not necessarily mean that you want to destroy their current session. Also, consider that in the general case a user may have session state without actually having logged in (e.g. shopping cart). What's your rationale for wanting to destroy their existing session?

Comment: There is a benefit to destroying the session. It ensures anyone who has gained access to their session id at some point in the past will no-longer be able to do anything with it. Tools like FireSheep allow single-click access to session id's from anyone else on the same LAN as you, this is a real possibility. Of course, they could always just steal your session id again after you log in. But maybe the login area is under SSL, while the rest of the site is not. It's an edge case for sure, but resetting the session at login will sometimes increase security.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert: If the whole site is not under SSL, they can steal your session cookie just after you login again. Resetting the session will not increase security, it will just make the single-click attack a double-click attack.

Comment: @Jon placing an entire site under SSL doesn't always make sense. I think any site with a login area should be under SSL (stack overflow doesn't), but for a website with 3,000 pages that don't require a login and 4 pages that do, I think only those 4 pages should be under SSL. And the session id should not be shared between them. Or even if you're less strict (like stack overflow) it does make sense to reset the session id before changing the password/etc. There is no reason not to, and it does increase security. Especially if you reset the session id immediately after changing the password.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert: Please provide some *technical justification* instead of simply rehashing the same phrase. I did not say that placing the entire site under SSL is a must; only that if you do not do that, your session *can* be stolen. **The only thing that placing the login page (only) under SSL offers is that the attacker can *only* steal your session instead of stealing your password and logging in themselves at their leisure in the future.**

Comment: The technical justification is that just because someone has stolen your session id in the past does not mean they are going to be able to steal your session id again in the future. Perhaps all future requests will be under SSL, or perhaps the new session id will only be valid for brief time, and the attacker doesn't have any way to make use of it in such a short period of time. It's not a big improvement, but it's one with zero negative side effects.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert: I am not going to argue further because "perhaps the new session id will only be valid of a split second" and such are not worthy of argument. You might want to read my previous comment again for some *technical* details. I have also already explained that the negative side effects are *not* zero: imagine if Amazon did what you suggest.

Comment: @Jon you're right, I've changed the wording a bit. It seems we are talking about two different things. I never suggested placing only the login page under SSL. We are talking here about resetting the session id before switching from a low-security area of the site to a high security area. I think that clearly does have some small benefit. It is trivial to bring the contents of the session over to the new session id by the way. Four lines of code. Amazon might very well be doing this (i'm not going to check).

Comment: @AbhiBeckert: The problem is that you *think* it has some benefit, but you cannot *show* it has. You might want to try asking in the PHP chatroom and point the people there to this discussion to get a second opinion.